# How to Decode Byte Array obtained From WebSocket Payload

Tags: web-scraping, websocket, decode, playwright, payload

I am trying to decode byte arrays obtained from a websocket using playwright (python). Here's a couple of example payloads:

1. b'#\x19d\xf3\x15\xa8R\xf5)L\xeb\x00\x00\x007\x00\x03k\xca4SsR9Vb8C6pXQzIjipesz9Se\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01_\x90\x00\x00\x80\x00'
2. b'#\x19d\xf3\x15\xa8Rqr\xfeD\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x03i\x1ba/W8cyOM0UpM6Q6/wPpZT/Q5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01_\x90\x00\x00\x80\x00'
3. b'\x00W\x00\xa9\xa4\xe2*1OC/UK_best_odds/market_3559116745/bet_26965297148\x0f\x02\x08_CREATOR\x1d"oddschecker","TOPIC_CONTROL"\x07REMOVAL\x16when no updates for 4h'

I would like to decode these byte arrays to a human-readable format. Note, there is sometimes human-readble text in the byte arrays.

I have tried using the [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) python package to detect the encoding type. However, it was unable to detect the encoding or returned unexpected results, here's an example output:

1. {'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None, 'language': None}
2. {'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None, 'language': None}
3. {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'IBM866', 'language': 'Russian'}